# Help required in understanding how the error of a convolutional layer is calculated when filter and delta of next layer have differing dimensions

Tags: neural-network, cnn, convolution, backpropagation

I am trying to implement a CNN in NumPy so as to better understand its inner workings

My architecture is as follows

- 10 images with 1 channel and with 28-pixel rows and columns (Dimension : (10X1X28X28))
- 3 convolutional filters. Each with the dimension 5X5. (Dimension: 3X1X5X5)(stride=1)
- First Convolutional Output with dimension (10X3X24X24)
- First Max Pooling Layer(stride=2)
- First Max Pooling Output with dimension (10X3X12X12)
- 6 convolutional filters. Each with the dimension 3X5X5 (Dimension : 6X3X5X5) (stride=1)
- Second Convolutional Output with dimension (10X6X8X8)
- Second Max Pooling Layer(stride=2)
- Second Max Pooling Output with dimension (10X6X4X4)
- First Fully Connected Layer of Dimension (96X10)
- Second Fully Connected Layer of Dimension (80X10)
- Output Layer of Dimension (10X10)(Softmax Layer)

Using backpropagation, I have been able to calculate the error of the second convolutional output, which has the dimensions 10X6X8X8. I need to calculate the error of the first max-pooling output. This involves the following steps

1. Take the convolutional filter that connects the first max-pooling output and the second convolutional output. This has the dimensions (6X3X5X5).
2. Rotate the 3rd and 4th axes by 180 degrees. In code that will be`resulting_weight = np.rot90(np.rot90(weight,axes(2,3),axes=(2,3))`
3. This results in the new rotated matrix that has the dimensions (6X3X5X5)
4. Do full convolution between the errors of second convolutional output(10X6X8X8) and the new rotated matrix(6X3X5X5)

I am unsure of how to implement the last step due to un-matching dimensions. The full convolutional operation should result in a matrix with the dimensions (10X3X12X12). This is made possible only if the rotated matrix has the dimensions (3X6X5X5). Should we re-shape the rotated matrix to have the dimensions (3X6X5X5)? Or is my understanding of the 180-degree rotation wrong?

Comment: maybe [this will help](https://towardsdatascience.com/back-propagation-the-easy-way-part-3-cc1de33e8397) in general the delta is transformed using already known matrices, either by transposition and/or entry-by-entry diff/gradient computation

Comment: also https://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/

Comment: these references will help you 1) https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5d79/11c93ddcb34cac088d99bd0cae9124e5dcd1.pdf, 2) http://courses.cs.tau.ac.il/Caffe_workshop/Bootcamp/pdf_lectures/Lecture%203%20CNN%20-%20backpropagation.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for these links! I came across this link that tries to explain the process of calculating the gradients of a convolutional layer. https://hackmd.io/@bouteille/ByusmjZc8#3-Convolutional-layer It seems to be a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes that link contains code from scratch using numpy, which is what you want. The main idea to match the shapes is the same, that is one does a reverse procedure than forward propagation.